# Sense Resistor in Battery Charging Circuit

Tags: batteries, resistors, charger

I have a 3 18650 in parallel Li-ion battery pack and wish to use the LTC4162 as the charger and LTC2944 and the level indicator. I am unsure as to who to wire them to effectively use both. I noticed that they both have a sense resistor and worry that it will be redundant for both of them to have it. Is there a way to correctly use both parts on one battery? I don't think the 4162 makes for a good level indicator, although it has a sense resistor to measure battery current, it cannot display that information as effectively as the 2944 could. Can I use both? How do I?

[image: LTC4162 Charging Unit]

[image: LTC2944 Battery Life Level Indicator]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LTC4162 has the feature to regulate the battery independent of regulating the load to the power source for MPPT.

It appears, the LTC2944 can share the same Rsense to the high side of the battery, but I did not confirm everything.  The LTC4162 has ICHG(MAX) = 32mV/RSNS using the suggested the "Kelvin method" 4 trace pad Layout.

Now you can have a gas gauge for the SLA pack with MPPT to the current source with CC,CV and cutoff to the battery, with important temp compensation CV settings while the charger can operate the load at the same time and count Coulombs with LTC2944.

However the Rsense value for the LTC2944 must be chosen based on a [different algorithm](https://www.analog.com/media/en/dsp-documentation/evaluation-kit-manuals/dc1812afa.pdf) which may result with incompatibility if sharing the same Rsense, so they would have to be serial and which of course raises the battery ESR if put between the battery and the other Rsense.
[image]
The LTC4162 does perform some smart tests that can tell you the cell state  from pulsed load tests and no load cell voltages, where this may be used in conjunction with some algorithm to integrate battery current and time with no load voltage to get an estimate of SoC.

It's my hunch that the LTC2944  provide some additional data for you to analyze and compare history about battery performance and if battery capacity has expired below some acceptable limit to warn the user from charge/discharge inefficiency or degraded capacity.

Usually, ESR and Ah capacity estimates over at least 1/3 of the voltage range are a good estimate for lead acid capacity extrapolation.

You must ensure the aggressive equalization frequency does not cause outgassing and drying out of the SLA by the optimal settings.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I will test putting the sense resistors in series and see how that goes. I do worry about how that may affect the reading for a sense resistor since putting them in series will change the current for the other one. I did propose this question with Analog and they recommended using the eval kits to test with the accompanying software to accomplish my goals. Will update later.